# Antivirus remove o programa após instalação/upgrade

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, antivirus

Antes, desculpe-me se não é o local, mas não estou conseguindo resultados nas minhas buscas por esta situação.

Bom estou com uma situação desconfortável, tenho um sistema desenvolvido em Delphi 7 e no processo de instalação ou atualização do programa no windows 8, 8.1 e 10, e alguns do windows 7 (minoria) que tem algum antivírus instalado é removido.

O mais interessante é que o programa de instalação/upgrade é acionado e tudo corre perfeitamente, sem maiores problemas, porém basta o terminar a instalação e pronto o antivírus remove o programa.

Como posso instalar sem que o antivírus remova o programa?

att

Luiz Marcelo.

Comment: Zona de exclusão, lista branca, etc, vai depender do antivírus.

Comment: Seria a area certa a postar se você mostrar como o programa é feito e no minimo dizer qual tipo de virus o antivirus acusa. Fica muito ampla se você não der detalhes e torna impossivel responder. Você já tem um bom tempo de casa pra saber como criar uma pergunta "respondivel" aqui, por favor edite e de detalhes. Não só o tipo de virus, mas como é código, etc. Recomendo que leia o Help se não entendeu. Leve como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Não acusa vírus algum no relatório apenas há possível ameaça e o programa é excluído.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem isso que o Luiz comentou. Depende do antivirus

Ele remove o seu programa devido a "baixa reputação do desenvolvedor",sem ofensas. Pois seu sistema não foi criado por uma empresa conhecida por ele.

Então terá que analisar o procedimento para informar a cada antivírus que ele pode "confiar" no seu sistema.

Isso é feito usando zonas de exclusão que são pastas que o Antivirus não escaneia ou listas brancas que são listas de programas confiáveis.

O grande problema é ter que fazer isso em cada computador que o programa for instalado.

Comment: Obrigado! Não tem muito o que fazer, uns instalam sem problemas outros não. Saber qual irá reportar o erro não tem como. Repassei ao Suporte e estão atuando neste formato, "desligam" o anti-virus instalam o programa e habilitam novamente o anti-virus.